# Fastest way of loading large data from query

Tags: c#, oracle11g, datatable, datareader, dataadapter

I know there were many disscussions about what is fast when we talk about fetching data from DB. But still, my problem is that I need to load a huge amount of data (between 20.000 rows - 5 million rows, based on conditions which user executes), in order to export all that in Excel worksheets, from DatagridView.

I know I could set pagination of query in DatagridView & I have allready tested that (which works nice & fast btw), but bottom problem of exporting to Excel still exists, so I need to fetch everything. Currently what I have done is to load data in different thread, so that UI doesn't freeze while fetching data.

Query in DB is optimized as It get's - unfortunally It's not a simple one since It uses even DB links with joins to produce final resultset. But from the point of DB we can't do nothing else.

I allready tested all I could think of - working with DataAdapter.Fill & DataReader.Load methods, with Datasets,DataTable and even List < T >. I did all of these in order to see difference between perfomances (speed vs. memory usage).

Results were actually a bit surprising to me - with all talking about DataReader.Load speed over DataAdapter.Fill method, and filling List < T > over  DataTable, I came to a conclusion that in my case all statements doesn't apply quite as It supposed to:

1.) Filling List < T > was slower than filling DataTable, but lower memory consumption;

2.) DataReader.Load vs DataAdapter.Fill is almost no difference at all - sometimes first wins, sometimes not, and differencies are in couple of seconds.

Anyway, nothing I tried haven't produced desired results, since my data for about 2 millions of rows is loading around 5 minutes (at It's best case).

**Is there anything I have missed that beats all these methods when It comes to filling data in terms of speed ? Maybe some caching ?**

For any advices thanks in advance !

P.S.: I would be satisfied just with a plain answer on where to start, that's why I didn't include any code.

Comment: Are you sure your results are not being 'corrupted' by caching on the DB?  It is possible if you are executing the same query multiple times in fairly quick succession.

Comment: 20K rows is no data. 5M rows is *some* data but neither big or huge. Reporting databases and data marts work with many millions of rows and TBs of data. The speed of loading the data depends on the *query itself*, the disk speed and the network. YOu didn't mention how much data you're trying to load so it's not possible to guess whether the disk or network are saturated. You *can't* load data faster than the network allows

Comment: Besides, *why* are you trying to load that data in the first place? What are you trying to do? Does that **really** require moving 5M rows to the client before processing starts? Perhaps you should just write appropriate queries to process the data in the database itself. 5M is *smallish* for a star schema - a small departmental data mart perhaps. Even if you can't write one query to produce the result you want, you could write one that calculates aggregates like counts, sums, averages, far faster than the client could.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, as I said we can't do nothing else in DB, or at least what we could think of. We investigated Oracle execution plan and optimised query as we could. I would rather think of how to fill data faster from .NET. As example, from OracleTOAD client : 2 mio of rows get executed in 50 seconds - total row count under 2 minutes. I'm trying to get near that.

Comment: Even if you need to move all the data to the client, you *don't* and *shouldn't* try to keep it in memory. For one thing, any code you write that works on Lists and DataTables will be far slower than what the database can do using indexes, multiple cores and smart join strategies. For another, why wait for all 5M rows to arrive before you start processing? You could read rows one by one from the DataReader and process them as they arrive. Once you do that, there's no reason to keep rows in memory

Comment: @Lucy82 *what* are you trying to do in the first place? You didn't provide any information. Besides, I doubt that TOAD loads *all* 2M rows data and displays it in a 2M row grid control. Most likely it loads *some* of the data and displays it while waiting for the query to finish. Just like reading and processing data from the DataReader directly instead of trying to load all 2M rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes I would probably need to do sometinhg like that, but still exporting to Excel is what my problem is. Users need to send all data in Excel to other companies, we are in financial bussiness where we collect and monitor bank transactions. That is a must, unfortunally. And currently my code for Exporting to Excel needs all Datatable at once.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I said that TOAD loads in 50 seconds, how many rows I don't know. It paginates after 500 rows, but reloads next page fast. And record count is about 2 minutes long.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, about processing rows as they arrive : It's a simple context menu for Datagridview, where user can choose export to Excel. Should I create Excel in background, before user clicks on that button ? Though this won't solve my speed issues, and I should disable button until processing complete.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos " The speed of loading the data depends on the query itself, the disk speed and the network" . I dont understand What do you mean by disk speed and network .What are their roles in loading data.Could you please elaborate a little bit as I am trying to understand

Comment: @Lucy82 `record count is about 2 minutes long.` this has *nothing* to do with .NET, that's just a SQL query. As for exporting to Excel, 1) you can't have more than 1M rows in Excel. 2) You can create a real `xlsx` file directly with libraries like Epplus or ClosedXML, so you don't need a List or DataTable. With Epplus it could be as easy as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataReader()`. This will still take a lot of RAM because Epplus constructs a model in memory before saving it to disk. This is still a *LOT* better than waiting to load everything in a List or DataTable before exporting

Comment: @Lucy82 as for the List<T> (and probably the DataTable too), a large part of the delay is caused by buffer reallocations and garbage collection. A list stores items in a buffer. When it runs out of space, it creates a new buffer with twice the size and copies the data over. The old buffer remains in memory until it gets GCd. Adding `M items (2^20) would require 20 reallocations and *double* the RAM. To avoid this you need to specify a capacity when creating a list.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I allready have OpenXML for Excel, Sax method, very fast. Exporting to more than 1 million rows also not problem, code creates next .xlsx for that. So let's cut disscussion - I have tried everything there is and nothing will give me better results ?

Comment: @Lucy82 in that case why are you using a List or Datatable at all? Use the DataReader directly to read one row at a time and add the element to the sheet. That's what the SAX method is about too - work on individual items, not the entire DOM at once. That's the point of the *entire* discussion. That you *don't* need to load everything in memory, in fact you *shouldn't*, if you need to handle a lot of data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Ok, I will try to set List capacity, I haven't tried It.

Comment: @Lucy82 that's not what I said. That's still far slower than simply using the reader. Why do you want to use that List in the first place? You don't need it since you already use the SAX method. If you want to add totals to Excel, don't calculate them on the client. One option is to add groups to an Excel table and have the end user's Excel calculate them. Another option is to calculate then in the database with other queries. Oracle's parallelized aggregate operations will be far faster than doing the same thing in the client, even with PLINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Ok, let me get this straight. What you suggest is: 1.) load paginated data into Datagridview, not entire resultset otherwise they will stiil have to wait for viewing data (we didn't mention that at all), 2.) when user right-clicks on contextmenu for Excel export, use Datareader and write Excel using SAX, but they will just have to wait as they wait now for DataTable or List load. And no memory consumptions by doing this. Am I correct ?